# How to add a Folder under specific Test plan folder in QC using Excel Macro

Tags: vb.net, macros, hp-quality-center

I am trying to add a new folder in QC12 under specific folder (Rot -> 2016_01_janrelease -> functional) using Excel Macro. Can someone provide a piece of code for the same?